# How can I handle an account - product relationship in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to create a relationship like accounts (identity) can have multiple products but products can only have only one account. I separated `DbContext` and databases by two but when I try to add second product to the `DbContext` with the same account, I get an error about "account primary key duplication".

How can I handle these relationship? Should I use separated `DbContext` or just have one instead?

Comment: Are you asking how to do a many-to-many relationship in EF Core ASP.NET Core? If so, [there is documentation on that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many). I don't know why you need to split into two different contexts.

Answer (score 2):

> I seperated db contexts and databases by two

Time for documentation. What the heck did you even think doing that? There is no reason for more than one db context.

> but when I try to add second product to the db context with the same account,
> it gives a account primary key duplication error.

Documentation and examples. These will help more than us debugging code you do not bother to share with us.

> Should I use separated db contexts or just have one instead?

Well, what is your reason for a maintenance nightmare? There are some scenarios more than one db context makes sense (like: Accessing separate databases with separate schemata or 2 separate apps sharing one database), but generally it falls straight into "wtf" territory. One database, one db context (automatically generated in many cases).

Comment: I actually asked the same question with the codes 5 hours ago but no one has answered. But I understand thanks, I have been trying to solve this problem for hours. I will use one dbcontext one database.